# setNextRequest() in Postman

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I am trying to set a request after a certain request in postman, but It is not working as I want it to be. I have read through Postman documentation but got no luck. Plus, how do I get postman's request ID?

I am using the given JavaScript in the Test tab, and in postman documentation it says it should work. But no luck.

postman.setNextRequest('Login');

Comment: It would be helpful if you can share your collection. And also can you explain what is the exact problem you are facing? like what is the outcome you are expecting and what is the outcome you are getting ?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57609395/postman-setnextrequest-unable-to-pass-request-id

Comment: @AvishekSaha Please refer to this screenshot: https://www.screencast.com/t/jwZK9z1K

Comment: Can you make sure that `postman.setNextRequest('Login');` is inside a test script of a request which is inside the same collection where the `login` request resides?

Comment: Yes it is inside the same collection.

Comment: `setNextRequest()` only works inside the Runner. It will be ignored if you just press the `Send` button and dispatch your request. Please, make sure that this is not the issue here. @ArslanAhmed

Answer (score 3):

`postman.setNextRequest('Login')` will work only inside the Runner. Also, the requests need to be in the same Collection.

Even if the request is in another folder (while still in the same collection), you can reference it in `setNextRequest()`, without having to specify any folder.

And to answer your second question, "how to get the Postman Request Id?"
Use this `pm.info.requestId` which will return string value, you may set that in environment variable as well, like `pm.environment.set("rID", pm.info.requestId)`

Comment: In the new UI, you can also find it the ID by clicking on the request you want the ID for, the, go to the (i) button in the far right sidebar (where you usually grab the curl, e.g.). The code way is probably safer against maintenance-introduced issues, though.

Comment: I can get it just fine in the UI as stated above, but how do you USE it? Passing the GUID in `setNextRequest("GUIDhere")` does not succeed. This would enrich this answer, as it can't be found elsewhere. Thanks!

Comment: What if you have a request with the same name in the same collection? It happens a lot in our collection. The Postman documentation is silent about this...

Comment: @Kreidol, if you're taking the request ID from the Postman UI (the "i" button), then note that that id also contains the user id as a prefix, a mentioned in the docs here: "Note that the ID shown is the user ID followed by the request ID. **Omit** the first eight digits and dash to get the request ID"

Comment: Circling back to this, as I figured it out ages ago and lost the thread. You pass it by removing the first section of GUID characters and sending it as a string.

Given `12345678-2222483b-0555-4c49-a97f-65836bf3d811`, send `pm.setNextRequest("2222483b-0555-4c49-a97f-65836bf3d811");`